# Line chart with team sum up

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, chart

I have a list with columns `Teams`, `Manual Minutes` & `Auto Minutes`

[image]

I am trying to get a line chart with the sum of `Manual Minutes` in one series and a sum of `Auto Minutes` in another. Team name should be in x-axis.

When I try to group by team name in charts it is not working.

Can anyone let me know how I can achive this?

Comment: Are you using SharePoint 2013? Is a workflow with loop an option?

Comment: I'm using SP2010..